# How to change title backgroundColor by using lookupReference in extjs

Tags: javascript, css, extjs

I m using `lookuprefernce` to get values. I want to change background color.

```
var LRMainPanelRef = this.lookupReference('MainPanelRef'); 

var titletext = LRMainPanelRef.items.items[1].title;
```

I want to set back color and want to use something like this 
dont know how to do it ..I am trying this

```
LRFMainPanelRef.items.items[i].title.backgroundColor= "#FFEFBB";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change background color of title using [`getHeader()`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.panel.Panel.html#method-getHeader).

Eg:

```
var mypanel = this.lookupReference('mypanel');//mypanel is reference of Component
mypanel.getHeader().setStyle('background-color', '#FFEFBB');
```

In this **[FIDDLE](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2fpp)**, I have created a demo. It's showing, how to change color of title bar uisng `lookupReference`. I hope this will help/guide you achieve your requirement.

**CODE SNIPPET**

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function () {
        Ext.define('MyViewController', {
            extend: 'Ext.app.ViewController',
            alias: 'controller.myview',

            // This method is called as a "handler" for the change color button in our view
            onChnageColorClick: function () {
                var mypanel = this.lookupReference('mypanel'),
                    header = mypanel.getHeader();

                header.setStyle('background-color', '#FFEFBB');
                header.el.down('div.demo-title').setStyle('background-color', '#ccc');
            }
        });

        Ext.define('MyView', {
            extend: 'Ext.Panel',

            title: 'Demo',

            controller: 'myview',

            items: [{
                xtype: 'button',
                margin: 5,
                text: 'Change BG Color of below panel title',
                handler: 'onChnageColorClick', // calls MyViewController's onChnageColorClick method
            }, {
                xtype: 'panel',
                title: 'Click to above to change My color <div class="demo-title">Hello I am DIV</div>',
                reference: 'mypanel'
            }]
        });

        new MyView({
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            width: 400,
            height: 200
        });

    }
});
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getView' of null got this error when I tried  LRpanelone.getView().getHeader().setStyle('background-color', '#FFEFBB');

Comment: why you written .getView()? instead of that use this `LRpanelone.getHeader().setStyle('background-color', '#FFEFBB'); `

Comment: you could use  this `header.el.down('div.demo-title').setStyle('background-color', '#ccc');`. I have updated my answer and [FIDDLE](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2fpp) please check