# How to change background color of html from Title

Tags: javascript, java, extjs

I have

Title and html text I want change background color of html 
I am using lookup refernce to get values from title and html

```
var MainPanelRef = this.lookupReference('MainPanelRef'); 

 var title = MainPanelRef.items.items[1].title;

var htmltext= MainPanelRef.items.items[1].html;
```

I want to change color for html like I did for Title

```
 MainPanelRef.getHeader().setStyle('background-color', '#00000');
```

please tell me how to change color same like title for html text 
//sample code

```
   if (htmltext.includes(str)){
```

`MainPanelRef.getHeader().setStyle('background-color', '#00000');
 MainPanelRef.getHeader().html.setStyle('background-color', '#00000'); //not working`
}

Comment: Do you have a live example?

Comment: please check code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change title backgroundColor by using lookupReference in extjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49903644/how-to-change-title-backgroundcolor-by-using-lookupreference-in-extjs)

Comment: yes but I want to do it for html text from Title